# using "uniq" and ignore the first chars, instead of words

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, shell

i have a list of files in a folder. the list of files is displayed using:

```
ls
```

now, i want to pipe that to uniq so it'll ignore the first 6 charactes before comparing.
is it possible? or perhaps i need to use another command?
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pipe the output of `ls` first to `sed` to strip away the first X characters and then pipe it to `uniq`.

```
% ls | sed -e 's/.\{X\}//' | uniq
```

(note: replace `X` with `6` in your case)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-s` (`--skip-chars`) option if your version of `uniq` has it.

```
ls | uniq -s 6
```

or

```
ls | uniq --skip-chars=6
```